# Agora RTM(Real Time messaging) in android

Tags: android, agora.io, rtm

I am trying to create messaging app for my project using agora RTM. I have downloaded the demo app for android but the problem is, it is asking me userId(Account). I dont know which userId it is asking me. Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is referring to the unique UID of the user whether remote or local, this can be a string or UInt